# Firebase FirebaseAuthClient class being deprecated

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an App build within Angular JS and Firebase.
Users can login thought their twitter.
I used the AuthClient.login ('twitter') function as show in the Firebase doc.
It works fine but since yesterday I have this strange message in my console:

> > FirebaseAuthClient class being deprecated. Please use      https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js and reference FirebaseSimpleLogin instead.

I have tried to include the simple-login.js file in my app and called the function SimpleLogin() but it doesn't work and it says the method do not exists.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include a code snippet? It should...

Comment: That s the login function: auth.login('twitter');

Comment: I'll need more than that. Can you create a repro in a JSFiddle and send me a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the fire-base-simple-login.js file and swap instead to call function:  FirebaseAuthClient() call  FirebaseSimpleLogin() and warning gone!!

Comment: FireBaseSimpleLogin is now deprecated as well: ["Firebase Simple Login is now a part of the core Firebase library. As a result, this standalone Simple Login client is being deprecated."](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login)