# Authentication Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to do a simple user registration login on Firebase, but I'm receiving this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FirebaseAuthClient is not defined

Here is my code:

```
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(rootRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    alert(error);
    return;
  }
  if (user) {
    // User is already logged in.
    doLogin(user);
  } else {
    // User is logged out.
    showLoginBox();
  }
});


function showLoginBox() {

  document.getElementById("#registerButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var email = document.getElementById("#email").val();
    var password = document.getElementById("#password").val();
    authClient.createUser(email, password, function(error,  user) {
      if (!error) {
        doLogin(user);
      } else {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `FirebaseAuthClient` from? I think that class has been deprecated for > 2 years. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487968/firebase-firebaseauthclient-class-being-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid problems with the FirebaseAuthClient class, you could try using the recently updated features for Authorization in Firebase:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account

After reading the new docs and creating an app, I found the easiest solution for registering users to be an e-mail & password auth. Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Here is some sample code:

```
 import Firebase

 //Register user
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email: String, password: String) { (user, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
 //user registered
 }

 //Login user
 FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email: String, password: String) { (user, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
 //user logged in
 }

 //Check if user is signed in
 if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
 // User is signed in.
 } else {
 // No user is signed in.
 }
```

Now, go get those users!

Comment: If you found my answer useful, I suggest accepting it. @Thalita Caetano

Answer (score 0):

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;         
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
```

Firebase token get from fcm FirebaseInstanceIdService.

```
mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(firebase_token)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new     OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            System.out.println("PRINT_DATACHANGE TASK  :" + task.isSuccessful());

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken", task.getException());
                       /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken_else");

                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i got this from firecast, you can login and register new user. It's pretty good for me, i use it with email and password auth, so no google auth. I also add simple redirect page when you already login and not login. if you alreay login, you will redirect to `dashboard.html`, and if you not login, you will redirect to `login.html`. sorry for my bad english.

```js
"use strict";
    const txtemail      = document.getElementById('txtemail');
    const txtpass       = document.getElementById('txtpass');
    const btnlogin      = document.getElementById('btnlogin');
    const btnreg        = document.getElementById('btnreg');
    const btnout        = document.getElementById('btnout');
    const texthiden     = document.getElementById('txthide');

    btnlogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const email = txtemail.value;
        const pass  = txtpass.value;
        const auth  = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    });
    btnreg.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const email = txtemail.value;
        const pass  = txtpass.value;
        const auth  = firebase.auth();
        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    });
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
        if(firebaseUser){
            console.log(firebaseUser);
            btnout.classList.remove('hide');
            window.location = "dashboard.html";
        }else{
            console.log('not login');
            btnout.classList.add('hide');
            window.location = "login.html";
        }
    });
    btnout.addEventListener('click', e => { 
        firebase.auth().signOut();
    });
```

you also can hide sign out button if you want, like `<button id="btnout" class="btn btn-default btn-group-lg hide">Logout</button>`. and javascript will unhide your sign out button `btnout.classList.remove('hide');`